# reconcile unable to talk with Consul backend

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

Im trying to setup a docker container for my vault/consul but get the following error:-

```
2017/06/22 18:15:58.335293 [WARN ] physical/consul: reconcile unable to talk with Consul backend: error=service registration failed: Put http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Here is my vault config file.

```
storage "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  redirect_addr = "http:/127.0.0.1:8500"
  path    = "vault"
  scheme = "http"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

#telemetry {
#  statsite_address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
#  disable_hostname = true
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is Consul?

This error is saying I'm trying to reach this URL: http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register and can't.

This implies that either Consul isn't running, or it's running somewhere other than at http://127.0.0.1:8500

Find your consul, and then update your config to point to it.